# Find lambda for exponential distribution knowing a percentage

Tags: exponential-distribution

Suppose that rainfall duration has an exponential distribution. From regular measurements is known that 20% of rainfall ends within one hour. Calculate the mean value of rainfall duration.

I guess this is about finding λ but I don't know how.

Thank you!

Comment: The 20% at 1 hour is referring to a value of the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).

Comment: I was thinking about that but how do you put in equation ?

Comment: Follow the link. $F(1hr)=0.2=1-e^{-\lambda\cdot 1hr}$. Solve for $\lambda$, whose units will be $\text{hr}^{-1}$, so the mean duration will be $1/\lambda$

Comment: Okay,I understand now, thanks